# Show that $(1,2]$ is neither open nor closed by arguing from the definitions.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, general-topology

I know that you can use the sequence $(x_{n})_{n=1}^\infty$ , $x_n = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$. We have $x_n \in (1,2]$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{n}) = 1 + \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}=1.$$ Hence $1$ is an accumulation point of $(1,2]$, but $1 \notin (1,2].$ Hence $(1,2]$ is not closed.

However I don't know how to then prove that it not open either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your sequence $(x_n)$ is not in $(1,2]$. Replace your sequence by $x_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$, and it will work.

Comment: so this is now correct?

Comment: yes it's correct !

Comment: The interval isn't open because every neighborhood $(2-\epsilon,2+\epsilon)$ of $2$ contains a point outside of the interval (specifically, it contains $2+\frac12\epsilon > 2$).

Answer (score 2):

For all $\varepsilon>0$, $(2-\varepsilon, 2+\varepsilon)\cap (1,2]^c \neq \emptyset$, so $2\in cl((1,2]^c) = (int(1,2])^c$, i.e. $2\notin$ the interior of $(1,2]$, so $(1,2]$ is not open

Edited: as pointed out by Arthur, we can just conclude after the first line: since $(1,2]$ does not contain any open ball centred at $2$, $2$ is not an interior point. There is no need for everything that followed from there

Comment: I agree with you on the first line (up to and including "$=\emptyset$"). However, if we're arguing from the definitions, then (depending on the OP's definition) we're basically done there. No need to fuss with the interiors and exteriors and complements. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Arthur what kind of definition allows us to conclude after the first line?

Comment: "A set is open if it contains an open $\epsilon$-ball around any point." Do you have another definition?

Comment: @Arthur indeed there isn't. I wonder how the hell did I miss that

Comment: so up to and including that point will be sufficient in my answer to this problem?

Comment: @ConnorDavies why are you so worried about your answer? Did you understand the idea? If you did you should be able to reproduce a proof on your own. There isn't a standard or algorithmic way to solve these kinds of problems

Answer (score 0):

The definition of an open subset E of a metric space is that every point of E be an interior point of E, and the definition of an interior point of a set E is a point around which there exists a neighborhood completely contained in E. (A neighborhood is an open ball of some radius $\epsilon$ around a given point.)

Every neighborhood of 2 contains points greater than 2, and no point greater than 2 is contained in $(1, 2]$. Therefore, 2 is not an interior point of $(1, 2]$, though it is a point of $(1, 2]$. Therefore, $(1, 2]$ is not open.